# Injury to knee, need advice

Tags: knees

I have a Meniscus Tear to my right knee, itself subject of an ACL rebuild 20 years ago.  I don't think I will have an op, as it is not completely severed. So I know I will need to strengthen my quads.

What exercises, once the swelling and pain has gone, can I do, in order to strengthen my quads, to reduce the chances of this happening again.  I know their are obvious ones, but are there any I could perform whilst sat at my desk at work?  I know I should wait, but is there anything I could be doing know, to lessen the impact on my quads as the onger it is inactive, the more muscle tone I will lose from it.

Thanks

**EDIT**

It's acutely painful at the moment, so I know I have to give it rest currently, and not rush back too quickly. I was injured 2 weeks ago, but then made it worse by twisting it at home the other day.

Exercises would be leg curls, squats and lunges, but obviously, only when healed. I was hoping for some advice, on maybe some ultra low impact exercises, like simply tensing the muscle, etc. I have another baby being born in 4 weeks and am desperate to be mobile, and fairly fit as it looks as though it may have to be a ceasarian section birth, which means wifey can do next to nothing for a few weeks. Apologies for the desperate nature of the post, but it's getting late!

Comment: What exercises do you know already and do you actually perform them? Besides, when did you get injured and how painful is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If rehab "speed" is your primary concern, I would consult with a professional who can tailor a program specifically for you.

Having said that, "**To the Googles!**".

Suggest perusing these articles for exercises that 1. you can do and 2. do not cause pain.  Do not try to rush this, give yourself at least week of exercise before you move to the next tier. Note that some of the suggested phases in the articles are multi-week.

### EXERCISES

**Meniscus tear: Rehabilitation exercises from [WebMd](http://www.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/rehabilitation-for-a-meniscus-tear).**

1. Quad sets
2. Straight leg raises
3. - Straight-leg raise to the front
4. - Straight-leg raise to the outside
5. - Straight-leg raise to the back
6. - Straight-leg raise to the inside
7. Hamstring curls
8. Heel raises
9. Unilateral stance
   10.Heel dig bridginga
10. Shallow standing knee bends

**The Sports Injury Clinic also has a [5-week program](http://www.sportsinjuryclinic.net/cybertherapist/front/knee/medial_meniscus/strengthening.php) you can follow.**

---

### RESEARCH

These may or may not contain useful information on the subject.

- [Meniscus Repair Rehabilitation](http://www.drwaltlowe.com/attachments/wysiwyg/File/MeniscusRepairProtocol.pdf) (pdf)
- [Intervention for High Performance / High Demand Functioning in Workers or Athletes](http://xnet.kp.org/socal_rehabspecialists/ptr_library/08KneeRegion/06Knee-Pain.pdf) (pdf)
- [Torn Cartilage Knee Injury Rehabilitation Stage 1](http://www.physioroom.com/injuries/knee/cartilage_tear_exer.php)
- [Exercises for Knee Rehabilitation](http://drmillett.com/downloads/rehab-protocols/kneescope.pdf) (pdf)
- [KNEE EXERCISE PROGRAM](http://www.athleticadvisor.com/images/acrobat/knee%20rehab.pdf) (pdf)

Comment: Nice comprehensive answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

- Custom-fitted, [custom-crafted arch supports](http://www.footsolutions.ca) (orthotics)
- Over-the-counter arch supports
- Add cushioned heel pads to your shoes
- Rocker bottom shoes
- Never walk barefoot
- Stretch feet and legs
- Ice and massage the foot